# Implement MLP in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I want to implement the MLP model taught in https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning, using *tensorflow*. Here's implementation.

```py
# one hidden layer MLP

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

W_h1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 512]))
h1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W_h1))

W_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([512, 10]))
y_ = tf.matmul(h1, W_out)

# cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_, y)
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_sum(- y * tf.log(y_) - (1 - y) * tf.log(1 - y_), 1)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(loss)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

# train
with tf.Session() as s:
    s.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    for i in range(10000):
        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        s.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})

        if i % 100 == 0:
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            print('step {0}, training accuracy {1}'.format(i, train_accuracy))
```

However, it does not work. I think the definition for the layers are correct, but the problem is in the *cross_entropy*. If I use the first one, the one got commented out, the model converges quickly; but if I use the 2nd one, which I think/hope is the translation of the previous equation, the model won't converge.

If you want to take a look at the cost equation, you can find it at [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10015/implement-mlp-in-tensorflow?noredirect=1#comment9892_10015).

## Update

I have implemented this same MLP model using *numpy* and *scipy*, and it works.

In the tensorflow code, I added a *print* line in the training loop, and I found out that all the elements in `y_` are **nan**...I think it is caused by arithmetic overflow or something alike.

Comment: I think those two cost functions expect different 'y_'.  The first wants the raw linear output and the second wants the linear outputs scaled between 1 and 0 by the sum of all categories.  The scaling can be done by tf.nn.softmax.

Comment: I don't think your first loss is what you meant to use. The common one is `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. Please take some time to read the official tutorial in tensorflow at https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/tutorials/mnist/tf/index.html#tensorflow-mechanics-101 or https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html#mnist-for-ml-beginners

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely 0*log(0) issue.

Replacing

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_sum(- y * tf.log(y_) - (1 - y) * tf.log(1 - y_), 1)
```

with

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_sum(- y * tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(y_, 1e-10, 1.0)) - (1 - y) * tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(1 - y_, 1e-10, 1.0)), 1)
```

Please see [Tensorflow NaN bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712178/tensorflow-nan-bug).

Comment: I kinda thought it is like 0 * log(0) problem. I just could not find a way to solve it in TF. Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think is that nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits expects unormalized results, where as the function you replace it with `cross_entropy = tf.reduce_sum(- y * tf.log(y_) - (1 - y) * tf.log(1 - y_), 1)`

Expects y_ to be normalized (by the sigmoid) between 0 and 1

try replacing

```
y_ = tf.matmul(h1, W_out)
```

with

```
y_ = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h1, W_out))
```

Comment: Sorry, thought it was worth a try, what does the output look like when you do this?

Comment: The `train_accuracy` is about **0.1**, for over 10k iterations.