# Tensorflow: Softmax cross entropy with logits becomes inf

Tags: tensorflow, histogram

I am working on the [Tensorflow for poets](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#4) tutorial. Most of the time, training fails with an error `Nan in summary histogram`.
I run the following command on the original data to retrain:

```
python -m scripts.retrain   
   --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks   
   --model_dir=tf_files/models/   
   --summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/"${ARCHITECTURE}"   
   --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb   
   --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt  
   --image_dir=/ml/data/images
```

This error occurred in [other mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526858/inception-retraining-issue-nan-in-summary-histogram-for-histogramsummary) as well. I followed the instructions there using tfdg which gave me a bit more insight (see below). However, I am still stuck because I do not know why this happens and what I can do to fix it without much experience in TF and neural networks. This is especially confusing because it happens with 100% tutorial code & data.

Here is the output from tfdg. The first time the error appears:

[image: tfdg output for the node with the error]
And the node in detail:

[image]

To look at the retrain script you can find Google's original code [here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/master/scripts/retrain.py). It was not modified in my case. Sorry for not including it (too many characters).

**Hyper parameters & result**
For additional information: trainings works with ridiculously small values for learning rate (e.g. using 0,000001). However this does not lead to good results. No matter how many epochs I train, performance stays on a low level (probably being stuck in local minima during optimisation).

Comment: You should include the code

Comment: Good point, I added the link @Maxim. It is the original Google code for this tutorial.

Comment: @Gegenwind you need to include versions for TF, OS, CUDA (if used)

Comment: if you remove the summary histogram, is your training going through or not ? histograms have more difficulties to deal with outliers than training

Comment: It's actually kind of hard to get `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` to produce `inf`. I'm doing a few tests and only get good values or `nan` no matter what `logits` is, as long as `labels` is ok (doesn't have `inf` or similar, which I think is your case). Anyway, if each item belongs to one class, you can try [`tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) and see if it's better (you'll have to reshape your data a bit though).

Comment: @jdehesa: thanks for your thoughts! I replaced the cross entropy function with alternatives, sparse_softmax as well (classes are exclusive anyway). I still usually get the error. Mostly it occurs in the softmax calculation where the exp becoms too large. I know that Tensorflow implemented a way to prevent softmax from becoming inf (http://python.usyiyi.cn/documents/effective-tf/12.html) but for some reason it still happens. Are you aware of any typical data-related issues that might cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had searched about compatibility as I was doing in 2.7 also, but it said 3.5 is the best version now with all latest tensorflow support. So I created virtual environment with python 3.5. I think that's why the stability issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure tf_files folder is being created?
I faced some issue on command line python. I switched to spyder and changed the variable data of input as required in retrain.py and it runs smoothly. I know, it's not a solution but a turnaround.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the folder is there, so this works. It seems to be more of a stability problem within the model.

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.7

Comment: I had searched about compatibility as I was doing in 2.7 also, but it said 3.5 is the best version now with all latest tensorflow support. So I created virtual environment with python 3.5. I think that's why the stability issue.

Comment: I will try that out and let you know, thanks for the hint!

Comment: @SaumyaAmbit Acharya: Thanks for our good intuition and for saving me many more hours of testing. A python 3 instance and it worked quite well. When you add it to your answer I mark it as the correct one.