# Tensorflow: How to convert NaNs to a number?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nan

I'm trying to calculate the entropy of the weights while training my graph and to use it for regularization. This of course involves `w*tf.log(w)`, and as my weights are changing some of them are bound to get into a region which results in NaNs being returned.

Ideally I would include a line in my graph setup:

```
w[tf.is_nan(w)] = <number>
```

but tensorflow doesn't support assigning like that. I could of course create an operation, but that wouldn't work because I need for it to happen during the execution of the entire graph. I can't wait for the graph to execute and then 'fix' my weights, is has to be part of the graph execution.

I haven't been able to find an equivalent to `np.nan_to_num` in the docs.

Anybody have an idea?

(For obvious reasons, adding an epsilon doesn't work)

Comment: [Try to avoid NaNs in the first place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712178/tensorflow-nan-bug/42497444#42497444).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you need to use tf.select.

```
w = tf.select(tf.is_nan(w), tf.ones_like(w) * NUMBER, w); #if w is nan use 1 * NUMBER else use element in w
```

---

**Update:** TensorFlow 1.0 has [deprecated](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6899) `tf.select` in favor of Numpy compatible [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where).

Comment: w = tf.where(tf.is_nan(w), tf.ones_like(w) * NUMBER, w) # version with tf.where - to copy faster and avoid confusion

Comment: For Tensorflow 2.0+ you need to use tf.math.is_nan. This code removes nans that where created by the padding portion of categorically_cross_entropy loss function:  
`loss_value = tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(loss_value), tf.zeros_like(loss_value), loss_value)`

Answer (score 0):

I use this to convert a value to 0 if it's NaN:

```
value_not_nan = tf.dtypes.cast(tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.is_nan(value)), dtype=tf.float32)
tf.math.multiply_no_nan(value, value_not_nan)
```

Answer (score -4):

You cannot convert nan to a number (such as you cannot convert infinite to a number).

The nan resulkts most probably from the `w*tf.log(w)` once w is (or contains) zero(s). You might add 1e-6 first so that no division by zero occurs.

Comment: In the original question he said he can't add an epsilon so I don't think adding 1e-6 will work.