# NaN from sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting NaN when I attempt to use the sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits loss function in tensorflow. I have a simple network, something like:

```
layer = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs, W1) + b1)
layer = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(layer, W2) + b2)
logits = tf.matmul(inputs, W3) + b3
loss = tf.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)
```

I have many classes (~10000), so I imagine I am getting NaN because the logit corresponding to correct class in at least one of my examples got truncated to zero. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It actually turns out that some of my labels were out of range (e.g. a label of 14000, when my logits matrix is just 150 x 10000). It turns out this results in a NaN rather than an error.

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by "labels out of range"? I think for each sample, the labels are a vector length matching the logit. I tried `a = tf.constant(np.array([[200.1, 20000.3, .5, .9], [1.0, 10000.0, 10.0, 10.0]]))
l = tf.constant(np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0]]))
s.run(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=a, labels=l))`. when the dimension not matching, it would complain about dimension; and if sum of probability > 1, it causes no error or `NaN`. what do you mean by "a label of 14000"?

Comment: The difference is that I was using `tf.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` so the inputs are the index of the label. When I say out of range, I mean I supplied (e.g.) the index 23, while only providing 7 logits to the function for each example.

Answer (score 5):

`tf.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` handles the case of `log(0)` for you, you don't have to worry about it.

Usually a `NaN` is due to a high learning rate of your optimization algorithm. Try to lower it until `NaN` errors disappear and the loss starts to decrease

Answer (score 1):

The `NaN` error probably occurs when one of the softmaxed logits gets truncated to 0, as you have said, and then it performs log(0) to compute the cross-entropy error.

To avoid this, as it is suggested in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712178/tensorflow-nan-bug/33713196#33713196), you could clip the values of the softmax output so that they are never zero.

```
out = tf.clip_by_value(out,1e-10,100.0)
```

Or you could add a small constant to avoid having zeros:

```
out = out + 1e-10
```

The problem with it is that the softmax function is applied on the logits internally by `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` so you can not change its behavior.

To overcome this, code the cross entropy error yourself and add the constant `1e-10` to the output of the softmax, not to the logits.

```
loss = -tf.reduce_sum(labels*tf.log(tf.nn.softmax(logits) + 1e-10))
```

Be aware that with the `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` function the variable `labels` was the numeric value of the label, but if you implement the cross-entropy loss yourself, `labels` have to be the one-hot encoding of these numeric labels.

**Update:** I have corrected the answer thanks to the comment by [@mdaoust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997378/mdaoust). As he said the zeros are only relevant after the softmax function has been applied to the logits, not before.

Comment: A logit of zero is nothing special. logits can be negative. Clipping to [-100,100] would be more reasonable, but may not solve the problem.

Comment: You're right, it only matters if the softmax output is zero, not if the logit is zero. Thanks!