# Training cost becomes nan with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, nan

I am practicing Neural Style Transfer and am facing an issue here with the costs. After few iterations, the costs become NaN.. What might be the issue here? Where should I try to focus on?

```
Iteration 0 :
total cost = 1919359.6
content cost = 125.083374
style cost = 47952.72
Iteration 1 :
total cost = nan
content cost = nan
style cost = nan
Iteration 2 :
total cost = nan
content cost = nan
style cost = nan
Iteration 3 :
total cost = nan
content cost = nan
style cost = nan
```

Generally I don't have a good plan how to figure out where the nan happens. Especially with TensorFlow, where I am not familiar with the debugging techniques.

The code is here: https://github.com/enyangxxx/neuralStyleTransferMonet
It is the code from a Coursera course and I want to apply it on my own themes later :)

Comment: make the learning rate as small as possible and give us another result?

Comment: Did you fix it? I'm having the exact same problem with the same exercise

Comment: sadly no, but hey, we can try to fix it together?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a mishandled 0/0 error. Especially the case if you have created your own functions. Most probably it might be cross entropy. I believe you are not training with keras and just tensorflow. May be check out this ->[Tensorflow NaN bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712178/tensorflow-nan-bug)

Then again this might not be your error. So it would be useful if you post the code.

Comment: Hi thanks for reaching out to me! https://github.com/enyangxxx/neuralStyleTransferMonet
here is the repo, feel free to have a look :) thanks a loot!